# Redirigir a pagina principal si ya se inicio sesión

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3, login

Cómo puedo hacer para comprobar si ya se inicio sesión, y redirigir al usuario a la pagina principal, de lo contrario redirigirlo al login.

Para el login tengo la siguiente función:

```
    $result = $this->cuenta_model->getLogin($user,$pass);
    if($result){
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $login = array(
                'user'=>$row->username,
                'usertype' => $row->tipo_rol,
                'logueado' => TRUE
                );
            $arreglo = array(
                            'username' => $row->username,
                            'fecha_acceso' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                            );
            $this->log_model->insertAccess($arreglo);
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($login);
        redirect('administracion/principal','refresh');
```

Todo ese código funciona, ya que si quiero recuperar si el usuario esta logueado obtengo del array de session la clave logueado que me devolverá true o false.

Sin embargo lo que quiero lograr es que sea tipo facebook, que si ingreso a www.facebook.com y ya tengo una sesión previamente iniciada me lleve a la seccion noticias, ya que actualmente si ingreso a la pagina del login de mi sistema igual sigue dejando loguearse aunque ya se haya iniciado sesión previamente.

Creo que se necesita usar cookies y javascript, pero no se cual es la lógica para hacerlo.

Que puedo hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La secuencia es más o menos así:

- Se almacena el id de la sesión en una cookie (las sesiones de php usan cookies) en el computador del usuario.
- Cuando el usuario regresa al sitio, se lee dicho id.
- Se ubica el dato de la sesión en el servidor, sea que esté en archivos, base de datos, etc.
- Se restaura la sesión en el punto donde quedó, esto ya depende de la lógica de tu aplicación.

No veo porque necesitarías javascript en este punto.

---

Algunos parámetros importantes a tener en cuenta:

- [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) es el más importante, pues por defecto está en 0, es el "tiempo de vida" de la cookie de sesión, lo puedes modificar en php.ini o con [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
- [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) es tiempo en segundos después del cual los datos de la sesión se verán como "corruptos" y se limpiarán.

Algo así puede hacerse al comienzo de los scripts:

```
$sessionTime = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$sessionName = "mi_sitio";
session_set_cookie_params($sessionTime);
session_name($sessionName);
session_start();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, como podría restaurar la sesión en el punto donde quedó?, esa parte no la tengo clara.

Comment: Esa parte ya depende de tu aplicación, digamos que vas almacenando la última url a la que el usuario navegó, pero eso no va ligado necesariamente a la sesión, pues la cookie de sesión de php solo almacena el id de esta, revisa `session_id()`

Comment: básicamente tengo que almacenar en algún sitio la url, ya sea DB o archivo, y desde ahi llamar la ultima url?

Comment: Exacto, a menos que lo quieras hacer en una cookie, incluso en la de la sesión `$_SESSION['last_url]='.....'`, pero puede ser o no una buena idea, dependiendo lo importante o no de la información. Las cookies cuentan como "user input" y por ahí también se abren muchos huecos de seguridad.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, lo voy a probar, :)